# Hibernate Session.LockRequest setTimeout method not working?

Tags: hibernate, locking, settimeout

I'm working with hibernate 3.5.4, SQL server 2012 and trying to build a method for X entity to controll simultaneously updating.

```
public void update(){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.buildLockRequest(LockOptions.UPGRADE.setLockMode(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
            .setTimeOut(1000)).lock(this); // Set TimeOut 1s
    System.out.print("Locked\n");
    try{            
        Thread.sleep(10000); // sleep 10s
    } catch (Exception e){};
    //Do something here
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();
    System.out.print("Unlocked\n");
}
```

I have two instances of X with the same id = 1.

```
    X a = session.get(X.class,1);
    X b = session.get(X.class,1);
```

I want to get an exception when `a` and `b` execute `update()` method at the same time, but nothing throws any errors.

```
    a.update();
    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception e){};
    b.update();
```

Console logs:

```
    Locked
    UnLocked
    Locked
    UnLocked
```

Does it mean that `setTimeOut` method works not properly when it still waits and then continues instead of throwing an error because of timeout?